# Looking for International Platforms for Self-Publishing Technical Books

Tags: ebook-management, publishing

I am a technical book author looking to sell my work internationally. I have been publishing my technical books on a platform called 'Zenn'(https://zenn.dev/books/explore) in Japan, and I am wondering if there are similar services available for international audiences. The Leanpub site is close to what I have in mind, but I am looking for a site with a little more natural science content.

Specifically, I am looking for platforms that:

Allow individuals to publish and sell their own technical books.
The content is weather data analysis and bioinformatics.
Operate by taking a commission from the sales.
Mainly focus on digital publications.
If anyone is aware of such platforms, could you please share the information?

Comment: KDP is one of the most popular platforms for E-Books of all categories

Comment: And a few more suggestions to research ... 
Apple Books, KDP (of course), Ingram Spark, Blurb.com, Lulu, Draft2Digital, Troubador Matador UK, BookBaby, etc.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.